# Command with multiple arguments with discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am trying to make a command with various arguments like for example:
!Poll "This is the title" "This is the description" "This is the time"

The problem is that it only takes the first 2 arguments

[image]

This is the code:

```
    const input = args.toString();
const regex = new RegExp('"[^"]+"|[\\S]+"[^"]+', 'g');
const arguments = [];
if(!message.member.hasPermission("ADMINISTRATOR")) return message.reply("No no no.");
if(!args[0]){
    return message.reply(`Use: !poll "Title" "Desc" "tiempo"`);
}else{

    input.match(regex).forEach(element => {
        if (!element) return;
        return arguments.push(element.replace(/"/g, '').replace(/,/g, ' '));
    });
}


const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
.setTitle(`${arguments[0]}`)
.setDescription(`${arguments[1]}`)
.setFooter(`Time :${arguments[2]}`);

message.channel.send(embed);
message.reply(arguments);
console.log(arguments);
console.log(arguments[2]);
```

Comment: Probably due to how you get arguments, why you don't you use `message.content.split(regex)` ?

Comment: Don't use `arguments` as a variable, it overrides an existing variable: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments

Answer (score -2):

```
.setFooter(`Time :${arguments[arguments.length - 1]}`);
```

Comment: Can you explain what went wrong and why you posted this answer?

Comment: @Huskyy you need to provide some additional information on your answer, not just code. This is also incorrectly formatted, and it doesn't actually answer the question.